# Identify which volumes are needed for duplicity restore

Tags: duplicity

## Background

I've been running Duplicity backup with the `--s3-use-glacier` option, and I'd like to restore a single file. I'm running the command

```
duplicity restore --file-to-restore myfile.txt boto3+s3://mybucket/myprefix localdir
```

As expected, I get:

```
InvalidObjectState: An error occurred (InvalidObjectState) when calling the GetObject operation: The operation is not valid for the object's storage class
```

since I haven't yet un-archived the volumes from S3 Glacier to Standard storage class.

## The question

Is there any way to identify which volume(s) I need to access in order to complete this `duplicity restore` operation?

I know I could just un-archive everything, but that seems a bit wasteful in terms of S3 Glacier retrieval costs.

I've tried the `-v9` verbosity level to see if it'd print the volume it was trying to access, but no joy.

Comment: Hi, just noticing your post after posting [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74880566/mapping-of-file-to-volume-in-duplicity-duply). Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not; I ended up un-archiving everything